# command representation in crontab

Tags: python, django, cron, postfix-mta

Normally I have a crontab like:

```
1 * * * *  /home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site/manage.py notify_about_changes
```

- I have been raising serious issues with crontab execution at some times it raises an error that main.cf is missing and when I have have created a file main.cf
- Next fatal error it raised what etc/mailname is missing.
- To some extend I believe commands which are executing in terminal are not absolutely written in crontab. I have the commands below to execute my task

In the Linux Terminal I normally execute in this procedure:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ cd pam_site
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.development
$ python manage.py notify_about_changes
```

Task: To represent the above commands in crontab which would enable me to avoid any postfix/sendmail error and execute notify_about_changes.py(which sends email notifications in a timely manner)

Comment: You might have to reconfigure postfix: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519519

Comment: why do I need to re-configure postfix when the task is related with crontab ?

Comment: put all the commands you've typed at the terminal into a shell script and call the script from crontab.

Comment: @nizamMohamed thanks it worked
->karthikkr I recognized the problem by mentioning --settings=project.settings.development in the end of crontab command worked for me this was suggested by my team mate. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

finally I got the problem resolved as below:-

1.I re-edited the crontab as

```
$sudo crontab -e

*/1 * * * * /home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/python3.4 /home/praneeth/wru-pam/pam_site/manage.py notify_about_changes --settings=project.settings.development
```

2.restarted the crontab as

```
$sudo service cron restart
```

For every one minute I have been getting email notifications.